# AWSでWEBサーバーの400系や500系のエラー頻発を検知する方法は？

Tags: aws, monitoring

AWSを使っています。
WEBサーバーの死活監視としてRoot53からのhealth checkはかけていますが、
内部的に404や500エラーがページによって頻発しているような場合を検知する方法として、
みなさんはどのような方法をとっていますか？

apacheなどのWEBサーバーのログを解析するのか、
何かそれらを簡単に通知してくれるツールがあるのか、
どなたかご提案いただけませんか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ELB 配下のサーバに対しては、 CloudWatch で HTTPCode_Backend_4XX, HTTPCode_Backend_5XX というメトリックが取得できるので、Alarm を作成することができます。

Answer (score 1):

AWSに限定されない方法ですが、例外トラッキングなどを行うと実際のページ表示が別のホストによって救済されたとしても検知することができると思います。

- https://airbrake.io/
- https://getsentry.com/welcome/

どちらもApplication Serverレイヤーでの例外を通知することを想定しています。
WebサーバーのログなどであればLogEntriesのようなsyslog収集ツールなどに集めて抽出する形でしょうか。

- https://logentries.com/

Answer (score 1):

既にお使いのRoute 53のHealth Checkは200/300以外の応答コードでもエラーになりますので、400/500の応答コードが変えればRoute 53のHealth Checkで検知できます。ですので、CloudWatchのアラームを作成して、メールで通知させることができますよ。

”頻発”しているかどうかは、アラーム作成時の閾値設定で何回連続してエラーになれば通知するという基準にできます。